# Appear the data in text box from datagridview

Tags: c#

I have tow Textbox in my windows form application "C#" and one datagridview tools,
and I want ( if user click on any row in datagridview) ,the data in this row should appear in the tow text box
How I can Doing This Thing.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

#### Description

You can subscribe the DataGridView `CellClick` event.

#### Sample

```
// subscribe the event using code
yourDataGridView.CellClick += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(YourGridView_CellClick);

// handle the event
private void YourGridView_CellClick(object sender,
    DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewImageCell cell = (DataGridViewImageCell)
        yourDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];

   yourTextBox.Text = cell.Value;
}
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN - DataGridView.CellClick Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick.aspx)